# Let $f:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism. Let $N \triangleleft H$ be a normal subgroup. Show that $f^{-1}(N)$ is a normal subroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $f:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism. Let $N \triangleleft H$ be a normal subgroup. Show that $f^{-1}(N)$ is a normal subroup of $G$

By definition of normal subroup, for any element of $H$, which is mapped from $g$
$$f(g)Nf(g)^{-1}=N$$

Apply inverse function. Since it is an inverse of a homomorphism, it is a homomorphism.

$$f^{-1}(f(g)Nf(g)^{-1}) = f^{-1}(N)$$
$$= f^{-1}(f(g))f^{-1}(N)f^{-1}(f(g^{-1}))$$
$$= gf^{-1}(N)g^{-1} = f^{-1}(N)$$

QED

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is not a homomorphism, since $f$ is not assumed to be bijective. The notation just means preimage.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is completely wrong.

Notice that $$f^{-1}(N) := \{g \in G\mid f(g) \in N\}$$. I.e., the set of all element in the domain that get mapped to N. This is the preimage of $N$ under $f$.

This is not the inverse image of the set $N$, since the inverse function only exists when $f$ is bijective.

However, when the inverse function exists, the two things are the same sets and hence the notation is well-defined.

So, in your proof you can't use an inverse function because you don't know that it exists. Rather use the definition of preimage I provided.